# Error in simple OpenCv c++ program CodeBlock window 7

Tags: c++, opencv

When I try running the below c++ program in codeBlock on windows 7  I am getting the following error.

> "\test_opencv\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
>   C:\Users\Root\Desktop\test_opencv\main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
>   C:\Users\Root\Desktop\test_opencv\main.cpp:13: error: 'cvNameWindow' was not declared in this scope
>   Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 1 seconds)
>   1 errors, 0 warnings"

===============================================================
program

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include "cvwimage.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    IplImage *pImg;
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    if(argc==2 && (pImg=cvLoadImage(argv[1],1))!=0)
    {
        cvNameWindow("Image",1);
        cvShowImage("Image",pImg);
        cvWaitKey(0);
        cvDestroyWindow("Image");
        cvReleaseImage(&pImg);
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

=====================================
I have followed the steps given in this link to set up the opencv and codeBlock.
http://opensourcecollection.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-setup-opencv-22-in-codeblocks.html.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mistyped. You wrote "cvNameWindow" instead of "cvNamedWindow".